# Java -Get a Date between two Dates, Giving unexpected result

Tags: java, date, calendar

So i'm trying to get a random time between two set times. But the resulting date is not what I'm expecting.

I'm expecting a result that is within the two dates I give as the earliest and the latest, but I get a date thats on the next day, and it appears as though if I take the time i'm supposed to get and subtract 12 I get this answer.
This is the log get: http://prntscr.com/6205yh

`private long nextLong(Random rng, long n) {
        long bits, val;
        do
        {
            bits = (rng.nextLong() << 1) >>> 1;
            val = bits % n;
        } while (bits - val + (n - 1) < 0L);
        return val;
    }`

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public Calendar getNextDate() {
    try
    {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        String earliest = getConfig().getString("Date.Spawn Earliest");
        String latest = getConfig().getString("Date.Spawn Latest");

        // Format the hours and minutes into dates
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Date earliestDate = format.parse(earliest);
        Date latestDate = format.parse(latest);

        // Figure out the random time between the two
        long e = earliestDate.getTime();
        long l = latestDate.getTime();
        long d = nextLong(new Random(), l - e) + e;
        Date date = new Date(d);

        // Update the hours and minutes into a new Calander with todays day,month and year.
        Calendar then = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        System.out.println(date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes());
        then.set(Calendar.HOUR, date.getHours());
        then.set(Calendar.MINUTE, date.getMinutes());

        // If it is later then the random time and nows hours are still higher then the latest time; add 7 days to get next week
        if (now.after(then) && now.getTime().getHours() > latestDate.getHours())
            then.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);

        System.out.println("At the moment it is:  " + now.getTime().toString());
        System.out.println("Dragon will spawn at: " + then.getTime().toString());

        return then;
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}`
```

If someone could explain to me whats going on I would be very grateful.

Comment: Forgot to mention.

The earliest string is "08:00" and the latest is "23:59"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be better :)

```
Date dateStart;
Date dateEnd;
int diff = (int) (dateEnd.getTime() - dateStart.getTime());
Date randomDate = new Date(dateStart.getTime()
      + new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextInt(diff));
Calendar then = Calendar.getInstance();
then.setTime(randomDate);
```

Comment: Well, I think the OP's use of a custom `randomLong()` method implies that he wants to deal with durations longer than 2^31 ms (around 24 days). Of  course, then you could just divide everything by 10,000 and use a separate random number for the last 4 digits, which would work for the next 1300 years.

Comment: `if (now.after(then) && now.getTime().getHours() > latestDate.getHours())
            then.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);` now.after(then) compare millis , this is okay. But hour compares 0~23, today 10:00 may less than tomorrow 12:00, you will lost some time related to hours

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. Your algorithm is obviously better (way shorter and it works). I was just pointing out that the cast to `(int)` in the third line is not always safe if you are dealing with time intervals in the months order of magnitude.

Comment: So I've changed it to

 http://pastebin.com/2yDHun5y
 And it's a lot closer to what I want, Its just off a few hours. (Prob My fault)

Comment: It seems that when I try and set the calendar's hours and minutes it makes the hours wrong, So I've just used a Date and set the day, month and year.

Comment: `Calendar then = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);` use this to set Calendar time, your random algorithm is okay :)